# Throw Exception - with detalization: which cell contains incorrect values

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Got `method` which takes `two dimensional` `String array` as parametr, `size` of `array` must be `4x4`, next `method()` check if `size` is not correct, `method()` `throw new MyArraySizeException(arr)`, after `method()` must sum all elements of `array`, and if in `array` cell contains not `digital` value `method()` must `throw MyArrayDataException`  - with detalization, in which cell contains incorect values.

Method:

```
  private static final int COLUMNS = 4;
    private static final int ROWS = 4;

    private static int convertString(String[][] arr){
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length ; j++) {
                if (arr.length != 4 || arr[i].length != 4){
                    throw new MyArraySizeException(arr);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length ; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j].matches("[0-9]+")) {
                    result += Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
                }else {
                    throw new MyArrayDataException(arr);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

exception: `MyArrayDataException(arr):`

```
 private String[][]arr;

    public MyArrayDataException(String[][]arr){
        this.arr = arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                    System.out.println("Incorrect values in: " +"[" + i + "]" + "" + "[" + j + "] is " + arr[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Method()` work fine `exception` also work, problem is I don't like `sout`, and I want change
realization of `MyArrayDataException(arr)`. I want to use `super() constructor`, instead `sout`.
To pass incorect cell in `super() constructor`, how can I achieve it?

Something like this:

I want this exception in another class

```
//it's not work

      private String[][]arr;
        int test;
        int test1;
    
        public MyArrayDataException(String[][]arr){
            super(String.format("Incorrect values in '%d'", arr[test][test1]));
            this.arr = arr;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, printing to sysout in an exception constructor is indeed quite silly. You've got the right instinct.

The easiest way to get what you want is to make a `static` method which converts the string array into a printable value:

```
public MyArrayDataException(String[][] arr) {
    super(String.format("Incorrect values in '%s'", arrToString(arr));
    this.arr = arr;
}

private static String arrToString(String[][] arr) {
    // write code here
}
```

Note that this method more or less already exists: `Arrays.deepToString(arr)` will do it. However, that prints e.g. `[["Hello", "World"], ["Second", "Array"]]`, if you want a multiline aligned matrix bonanza you would have to use the above trick. If deepToString works for you, then you can just call that and forego writing arrToString yourself.

Comment: I want this exception in another class

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing that, @Dartweiler.

Answer (score 0):

One remark on your `MyArrayDataException`:

At the place where you detect that the array content isn't a valid positive number, you already know the indices where this happens. I'd make them (`i` and `j`) additional parameters to the exception constructor, so you don't need to re-scan through all the array searching for the error position:

```
    public MyArrayDataException(String[][]arr, int i, int j) {
        super(String.format("Incorrect value '%s' at [%d][%d]", 
                            arr[i][j], i, j));
        this.arr = arr;
    }
```

By the way, the logic in your re-scan is flawed: what about an element being `"abc123"`? This is illegal of course, but it doesn't match `"[a-zA-Z]+"`. The check had better been:

```
if (! arr[i][j].matches("[0-9]+"))
```